# The value entered in TextField is inherited

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a fill-in-the-blanks quiz app.
There are 5 question statements in one quiz, but when I move on to the next question statement, the value entered in the text field remains. Could you please tell me what are the possible causes?

```
class PlayGame extends StatefulWidget {
  final List document;
  List correctList = [];
  PlayGame({Key? key, required this.document}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlayGame> createState() => _PlayGameState();
}

class _PlayGameState extends State<PlayGame> {
  int quizNum = 0;
  int quizCount = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Center(
          child: Text(
            "$quizCount/5",
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      if (quizNum < 4) {
                        quizNum += 1;
                        quizCount += 1;
                      } else if (quizNum == 4) {
                        print(widget.correctList.length);
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Result()),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_circle_right_outlined,
                  size: 40,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        height: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
            child: TextWithBlanks(
                text: widget.document[quizNum],
                correctList: widget.correctList),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code I was taught here.　Words surrounded by "{}" are BlankWord.

```
class TextWithBlanks extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  static final regex = RegExp("(?={)|(?<=})");
  List correctList = [];

  TextWithBlanks({Key? key, required this.text, required this.correctList})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TextWithBlanks> createState() => _TextWithBlanksState();
}

class _TextWithBlanksState extends State<TextWithBlanks> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final split = widget.text.split(TextWithBlanks.regex);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, right: 30.0, left: 30.0),
      child: Text.rich(
        TextSpan(
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, height: 3.0),
          children: <InlineSpan>[
            for (String text in split)
              text.startsWith('{')
                  ? WidgetSpan(
                      child: blankWord(text.substring(1, text.length - 1),
                          widget.correctList),
                    )
                  : TextSpan(text: text),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the BlankWord.

```
class _blankWordState extends State<blankWord> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: widget.answerWidth,
      child: TextField(
        maxLines: null,
        cursorColor: Colors.grey,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        autofocus: false,
        maxLength: widget.answerLength + 5,
        onChanged: (enterWord) {
          widget.value = enterWord;
          if (enterWord == widget.answer) {
            if (widget.answerBool == false) {
              widget.answerBool = true;
              widget.correctList.add(widget.answer);
            }
          } else {
            if (widget.answerBool == true) {
              widget.answerBool = false;
              widget.correctList.remove(widget.answer);
            }
          }
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          counterText: "",
          hintText: widget.answerHint,
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My moving to next question do you mean navigating to new page or updating quiz number here and setting state?

Comment: This means updating the numbering of the quiz questions on the page.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the page by changing the quiz number also reset the value that you are sending to the blank widget. When the blank widget is updated the widget.value is being updated, and that value stays in the class and when a new blank widget is added the value is being sent to the blank widget again I think

```
widget.value = enterWord;
```

Comment: Could it be the missing call to "didUpdateWidget" on "_TextWithBlanksState" to refresh the "text" parameter?